# hAxis title text position in Google line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

An example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/beo4qjsg/1/

It's essentially the same code used for "Multiple line types" example [in Google Charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#examples), with one change. Specifically, I have the following in `options`:

```js
      var options = {
        width: 1000, height: 850, 
        chartArea: {left:75, top:75, height:450, width:550},
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        },
        series: {
          1: {curveType: 'function'}
        }
      };
```

The output image looks like this:
[image]

As can be seen here, the title for X-axis "Time" is quite far from the axis itself. Is there any way to bring it closer? It is important that I keep the `chartArea.height` set to a specific value, so that's something I cannot change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the option for `chartArea`, add an option for `bottom`

```
    chartArea: {left:75, top:75, width:550, bottom: 40, height: '100%'},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
}).then(function() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0, 0],    [1, 10, 5],   [2, 23, 15],  [3, 17, 9],   [4, 18, 10],  [5, 9, 5],
    [6, 11, 3],   [7, 27, 19],  [8, 33, 25],  [9, 40, 32],  [10, 32, 24], [11, 35, 27],
    [12, 30, 22], [13, 40, 32], [14, 42, 34], [15, 47, 39], [16, 44, 36], [17, 48, 40],
    [18, 52, 44], [19, 54, 46], [20, 42, 34], [21, 55, 47], [22, 56, 48], [23, 57, 49],
    [24, 60, 52], [25, 50, 42], [26, 52, 44], [27, 51, 43], [28, 49, 41], [29, 53, 45],
    [30, 55, 47], [31, 60, 52], [32, 61, 53], [33, 59, 51], [34, 62, 54], [35, 65, 57],
    [36, 62, 54], [37, 58, 50], [38, 55, 47], [39, 61, 53], [40, 64, 56], [41, 65, 57],
    [42, 63, 55], [43, 66, 58], [44, 67, 59], [45, 69, 61], [46, 69, 61], [47, 70, 62],
    [48, 72, 64], [49, 68, 60], [50, 66, 58], [51, 65, 57], [52, 67, 59], [53, 70, 62],
    [54, 71, 63], [55, 72, 64], [56, 73, 65], [57, 75, 67], [58, 70, 62], [59, 68, 60],
    [60, 64, 56], [61, 60, 52], [62, 65, 57], [63, 67, 59], [64, 68, 60], [65, 69, 61],
    [66, 70, 62], [67, 72, 64], [68, 75, 67], [69, 80, 72]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 1000, height: 850, 
    chartArea: {left:75, top:75, width:550, bottom: 40, height: '100%'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    },
    series: {
      1: {curveType: 'function'}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize now that I have made a mistake in my original question (jsfiddle code is correct though). I need to use `chartArea.height` and apparently I cannot use `chartArea.bottom` and `chartArea.height` together.

Comment: they can be used together, see updated answer above...

Comment: It works only when `chatArea.height` is set to 100%. If I change it to, say, 50% then the X-axis title moves far away from the axis. Say, I have a really long text in legend and to be able to fit the entire legend I increase the total plot size. That increases the `chartArea.height` accordingly and the graph looks too tall. What I want to do is to keep the `chartArea.height` a constant pixel value.

Comment: you can adjust `chartArea.top` to allow more room for legend, while `chartArea.height` = 100% -- otherwise, there is not a specific configuration to set position of the axis title. the only other option would be to manually add the axis title on the chart's `'ready'` event, you can use `getChartLayoutInterface` to determine where the title should be placed, see [chart methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods)

Comment: Adjusting `chartArea.top` creates empty space at the top, between the plot title and the plot itself. That said, you have given me enough to think about and work with; thank you!